# Using css in display star rating system result in PHP HTML

Tags: php, html, css

```html
<div class=" rating  ">
                <input  type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2" /><label for="star2" disabled title="Sucks big tim">2 stars</label>
            </div>
```

I have successfully done a star rating system in my application using CSS

the star rating consists of light grey when unselected and blue when selected. When the user selects and clicks submit they work correctly and don't lose their position.

However, I want to display stars that are light grey or blue and are not clickable. how do i do this

```css
 .rating {
          float:left;
        }

        /* :not(:checked) is a filter, so that browsers that don’t support :checked don’t 
          follow these rules. Every browser that supports :checked also supports :not(), so
          it doesn’t make the test unnecessarily selective */
        .rating:not(:checked) > input {
            position:absolute;
            top:-9999px;
            clip:rect(0,0,0,0);
        }

        .rating:not(:checked) > label {
            float:right;
            width:1em;
            /* padding:0 .1em; */
            overflow:hidden;
            white-space:nowrap;
            cursor:pointer;
            font-size:300%;
            /* line-height:1.2; */
            color:#ddd;
        }

        .rating:not(:checked) > label:before {
            content: '★ ';
        }

        .rating > input:checked ~ label {
            color: dodgerblue;
            
        }

        .rating:not(:checked) > label:hover,
        .rating:not(:checked) > label:hover ~ label {
            color: dodgerblue;
            
        }

        .rating > input:checked + label:hover,
        .rating > input:checked + label:hover ~ label,
        .rating > input:checked ~ label:hover,
        .rating > input:checked ~ label:hover ~ label,
        .rating > label:hover ~ input:checked ~ label {
            color: dodgerblue;
            
        }

        .rating > label:active {
            position:relative;
            top:2px;
            left:2px;
        }
```

Comment: Could the disabled attribute make your happiness ?

Comment: `result in different pages`  On the web requests are stateless, which means you must use some form of persistent storage to maintain state between requests.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateless_protocol  `Examples of stateless protocols include the Internet Protocol (IP), which is the foundation for the Internet, and the Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP)`

Comment: @JulesR i want to display a star with a light grey color or blue. and if the user clicks on them nothing changes, could you please tell me how to implement this

Comment: @ahmed add this https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_disabled.asp

Comment: @JulesR did not work, and still does not fix the color option

Comment: Fix it with css

Answer (score 0):

```css
.rating {
  float:left;
}
.rating:not(:checked) > input {
  position:absolute;
  top:-9999px;
  clip:rect(0,0,0,0);
}

.rating:not(:checked) > label {
  float:right;
  width:1em;
  /* padding:0 .1em; */
  overflow:hidden;
  white-space:nowrap;
  cursor:pointer;
  font-size:300%;
  /* line-height:1.2; */
  color:#ddd;
}

.rating:not(:checked) > label:before {
  content: '★ ';
  color: #e4e0e0;
}
.rating:not(:checked) > label:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '★';
  color: dodgerblue;
  left: 5%;
}

/* .rating > input:checked ~ label {
  color: dodgerblue;

} */

.rating:not(:checked) > label,
.rating:not(:checked) > label ~ label {
  color: dodgerblue;

}

/* .rating:not(:checked) > label:hover,
.rating:not(:checked) > label:hover ~ label {
  color: dodgerblue;

} */

/* .rating > input:checked + label:hover,
.rating > input:checked + label:hover ~ label,
.rating > input:checked ~ label:hover,
.rating > input:checked ~ label:hover ~ label,
.rating > label:hover ~ input:checked ~ label {
  color: dodgerblue;

} */

.rating > label:active {
  position:relative;
  top:2px;
  left:2px;
}
```

```html
<div class=" rating  ">
 <input  type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2" />
  <label for="star2" disabled title="Sucks big tim">2 stars</label>
 </div>
```

Sea this one